# Pattern for extracting a verse including start number up to but not including next number

Tags: regex

See the example text below. I have created this expression `\[\d+:\d+\][\s\S]*[^\[\d+:\d+\]]` to select extract a verse like  so:

> [14:5] And from henceforth you shall not ascend into heaven unto all
>   eternity, and ⌈in bonds⌉ of the earth the decree has gone forth to
>   bind you for all the days of the world.

The entire document is of this format:

> [14:1] The book of the words of righteousness, and of the reprimand of
>   the eternal Watchers in accordance with the command of the Holy Great
>   One in that vision. [14:2] I saw in my sleep what I will now say with
>   a tongue of flesh and with the breath of my mouth: which the Great One
>   has given to men to converse therewith and understand with the heart.
>   [14:3] As He has created and given ⌈⌈to man the power of understanding
>   the word of wisdom, so hath He created me also and given⌉⌉ me the
>   power of reprimanding the Watchers, the children of heaven. [14:4] I
>   wrote out your petition, and in my vision it appeared thus, that your
>   petition will not be granted unto you ⌈⌈throughout all the days of
>   eternity, and that judgement has been finally passed upon you: yea
>   (your petition) will not be granted unto you⌉⌉. [14:5] And from
>   henceforth you shall not ascend into heaven unto all eternity, and ⌈in
>   bonds⌉ of the earth the decree has gone forth to bind you for all the
>   days of the world. [14:6] And (that) previously you shall have seen
>   the destruction of your beloved sons and ye shall have no pleasure in
>   them, but they shall fall before you by the sword. [14:7] And your
>   petition on their behalf shall not be granted, nor yet on your own:
>   even though you weep and pray and speak all the words contained in the
>   writing which I have written. [14:8] And the vision was shown to me
>   thus: Behold, in the vision clouds invited me and a mist summoned me,
>   and the course of the stars and the lightnings sped and hastened me,
>   and the winds in the vision caused me to fly and lifted me upward, and
>   bore me into heaven. [14:9] And I went in till I drew nigh to a wall
>   which is built of crystals and surrounded by tongues of fire: and it
>   began to affright me. And I went into the tongues of fire and drew
>   nigh to a large house which was built of crystals: and the walls of
>   the house were like a tesselated floor (made) of crystals, and its
>   groundwork was of crystal. [14:11] Its ceiling was like the path of
>   the stars and the lightnings, and between them were fiery cherubim,
>   and their heaven was (clear as) water. [14:12] A flaming fire
>   surrounded the walls, and its portals blazed with fire. [14:13] And I
>   entered into that house, and it was hot as fire and cold as ice: there
>   were no delights of life therein: fear covered me, and trembling got
>   hold upon me. [14:14] And as I quaked and trembled, I fell upon my
>   face. [14:15] And I beheld a vision, And lo! there was a second house,
>   greater than the former, and the entire portal stood open before me,
>   and it was built of flames of fire. [14:16] And in every respect it so
>   excelled in splendour and magnificence and extent that I cannot
>   describe to you its splendour and its extent. [14:17] And its floor
>   was of fire, and above it were lightnings and the path of the stars,
>   and its ceiling also was flaming fire.`

I have been using https://regex101.com/ to test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track, but the marker for the start of the next verse should be a positive lookahead:

```
\[\d+:\d+\][\s\S]*?(?=\[\d+:\d+\]|$)
```

Note carefully the term `(?=\[\d+:\d+\]|$)` at the end.  This *asserts* that what follows is the start of the next verse, but it does not consume anything.  In addition, it checks if the end of the document has been reached, would also indicate the end of the final verse.

Note that what you were using, `[^\[\d+:\d+\]]`, won't work as intended.  This actually says to match any single character which is *not* `[`, `:`, `]`, or a digit.  It is just a character class, or a collection of possible characters, but not a pattern.

Follow the demo link below to see the regex in action.

### Demo

Comment: That is perfect I really appreciate the help on that.